# Dali JPA eclipse 4.4 changes

Tags: jpa, eclipse-plugin, dali

I have a question about difference in Dali JPA in eclipse 4.4 ( having org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core_3.4.0 ) compared to old 3.x versions running with org.eclipse.jpt.core_2.2.1 for example.
The synchronize classes job from old version org.eclipse.jpt.core.internal.synch.SynchronizeClassesJob has been removed in the latest versions. What can I use to synchronize the list of persistent classes in a persistence unit in persistent.xml in the new 3.4.0 version or should this be implemented additionally and is no more available as functionality from Dali JPA?

Best regards,
Kiril

Comment: You aren't supposed to use classes with `internal` in the package name [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html)

Comment: I see, normally I would not use such but I have some legacy code using it which I have to make work in 4.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is now buried in `org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.ui.internal.handlers.SynchronizeClassesHandler`. That ends up calling the method `org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.context.persistence.PersistenceUnit.synchronizeClasses(IProgressMonitor)`, which is where all the real behavior is. You might look at the `SynchronizeClassesHandler` code and use it to craft your own `Job` that ends up calling the `PersistenceUnit` method.